# how can i create dynamic panel for news in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In a web developer program (like asp with c#) we can create a panel with dynamic element in it, but in sharepoint I'm Confused.

Problem :

I need create a panel for newest news in my sharepoint site that automatically update when a news added.
In asp.net (or similar) I would add one grid view and connected it to a database table.
but here i don`t know What should I do.

1. What controls should I use
2. how to connect these controls to Database Table

I have a sharepoint site, and need have a news panel that show newest news to visitors.
so that this panel contain 3 parts:

1. a part shows subject
2. a part shows a thumbnail image news
3. a part shows body of news

Look at this :

[image]

I need to use some Controls to create it and fetch needed data from database (or sharepoint list )

Answer (score 1):

you can use some prebuilt webparts from codeplex.

If you want it custom than you should be looking into webparts!

if its webparts, than you have two options! either a standard webpart or a visual webpart:

im not going to go into what they are as the links from msdn go into detail! The only difference you need to know is that a webpart can be added to a webpart page and if you choose visual webpart than you have an ascx page added ontop!

I would go for visual webpart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413295(v=office.14).aspx

normal webpart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817(v=office.14).aspx

The steps as you noted in asp.net c# would be the same appart from the database well you could do that too! but in this instance we dont want to make loads of calls to the database server so we would use a list or library instead!

the key here isto make sure that you have the list setup correctly (id, title, description, image)

within your visual webpart create a skeliton that would show the news within the ascx e.g.

```
<div class="list">     
    <ul class="lists">    
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">             
            <ItemTemplate>                 
                <li >                     
                    <div>                         
                        <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NavigationUrl").ToString().Split(',')[0] %>" target="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OpenInNewWindow").ToString()=="1"?"_blank":"_self" %>">                             
                            <img src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl").ToString().Split(',')[0] %>" class="full" alt="Tile" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:relative; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden"/>                        
                        </a>
                    </div>                     
                    <div class="transBack" style='background-color: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TileColorImageUrl") %>;'>                         
                        <p><strong>                             
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>
                        </strong></p>
                        <p><strong>                             
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>
                        </strong></p>
                    </div>                 
               </li>             
            </ItemTemplate>         
        </asp:Repeater>  
    </ul> 
</div>
```

the code above is for one news item, it would create a list with its list items,

it creates a link with an image, so if you click on the image it will take you to that link location. below would be the title and the description.

within the ascx codebehind (c#) add the binding info to get all the list items within the list to our new list displayed within sharepoint webpart:

```
    public newsClass webpart { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        this.webpart = this.Parent as newsClass;
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPList list = web.Lists[webpart.ListName];
        DataTable Dt = list.Items.GetDataTable();
        Repeater1.DataSource = Dt; Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
```

the above you can simply copy pase ;)

the part that you need to change is `public newsClass webpart { get; set; }` becasue my class that will call the ascx is called newsClass. If your doing sharpeoint 2010 or using vs2010 than it creates the .cs class for you when you select to make a sharepoint 2010 visual webpart template!

now goto the .cs class, as i said mine is called newsClass, this will contain the create child controls and other events that you can override ect.

add this code to the top (within the class) so you can put in the list name when you come to edit the webpart ;)

```
    #region custom Webpart Properties [List Name]
    public string _ListName;

    [WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("List Name"),
    WebDescription("This is the list that the data will be pulled out from into the webpart"),
    Personalizable(true),
    Category("Custom Properties"),
    DefaultValue("zone")]

    public string ListName
    {
        get { return _ListName; }
        set { _ListName = value; }
    }

    #endregion
```

this next part as i said is auto generated for you:

```
    // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/newsWebpart/news/newnews.ascx";
```

its getting the webpart to reference to the visual ascx page that we created earlier.

the above should get you going! ;). If you get confused with what i did than you can do it within the code behind only!

so when you create a webpart, (visual webpart dont do anythin to the ascx)

go direct to the .cs that contains the refence to the ascx page! do as i did above, this time override the createchildcontrols.

it should look like this:

```
    #region custom Webpart Properties [List Name]
    public string _ListName;

    [WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("List Name"),
    WebDescription("This is the list that the data will be pulled out from into the webpart"),
    Personalizable(true),
    Category("Custom Properties"),
    DefaultValue("zone")]

    public string ListName
    {
        get { return _ListName; }
        set { _ListName = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/newsWebpart/news/newnews.ascx";

    private SPWeb web;
    private SPList list;
    private DataTable Dt;
    private Repeater Repeater1;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
            if (_ListName.ToString() != "")
            {
                    Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
                    ((VisualWebPart1UserControl)control).webpart = this;

                        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='mainnews'>"));
                        web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                        list = web.Lists[_ListName];
                        Dt = list.Items.GetDataTable();

                        Repeater1 = new Repeater();
                        Repeater1.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(Repeater1_ItemDataBound);

                        Repeater1.DataSource = Dt;
                        Repeater1.DataBind();
                        Controls.Add(Repeater1);


                        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            }
    }
```

so we create a custom feild input to put in the list name when we edit the webpart, then within the create child controls event we access that list, we attach the list results to the datatable and then attach that to the repeater! we then create an event for the repeate to loop though each item like so:

```
    private void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          string urlImageClick = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "NavigationUrl").ToString().Split(',')[0];

          string newwindow = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "OpenInNewWindow").ToString() == "1" ? "_blank" : "_self";

          string descTitle = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Title").ToString();

          string decripText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "descriptionText").ToString().Split(',')[0];
            decripText = decripText.Replace("\r\n", "");

            if (bannerzone == true)
            {
                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='newsitem'>"));

                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ImageUrl").ToString().Split(',')[0] + "' title='Newsflash 2' height='100%' width='100%'>"));

                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='newsitem-desc'>"));
                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h3><a target='_parent' title='"+descTitle+"' href='"+urlImageClick+"'>Newsflash 2</a></h3>"));
                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>"+decripText+"</p>"));
                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                Repeater1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
```

the above will repeate through each item going through above repeater event for each one building a list,

for more info on repeater control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295084.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

last stage is..... as we added classes to the html tags e.g. the div tags we can there for create a css file that we can change to match our design/layout liking ;)

create a file within desktop and name accordingly, give it the extension of css so mine is called news.css. goto visual studios and create a mapped folder to anywhere on 14hive, for sharepoint 2007 use wspbuilder (you need to build the folders youself :( ) once you have a location, i like it under _layouts (should be a default option to choose from), now within that folder create another folder, iv called mine news, now import the css file to that folder..... thats is it! you now need to add the css to the page! to do that you need to goto the createchildcontrols event again! at the top add this code:

```
CssRegistration.Register("/_LAYOUTS/news/newsstyles.css");
```

and that is it ;) , sorry for being vauge and long winded but it should give you a clear idea of where to head and what to do! obviously you would need to tweak my code to suit your needs but its doable and should be easy to understand!

more info on mapped folder: (tutorial)

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/21/deploy-files-to-_layouts-in-sharepoint-2010/

forgot to mention a database method would be similar just that you would need to call it through a stored procedure and than populate the datatable that way ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

or using sharepoint designer (database method):

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=794

Comment: +1 An exceptional good answer, Ali! It's great what you provide for the community!